# HTML / CSS two seemingly equal elements, positions differ

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a form in HTML. The best way I can explain is showing my code.

**HTML:**

```css
form div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
.inputContainer {
  display: inline-block;
}
.inputContainer input {
  display: block;
  width: 14em;
}
.inputTitle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <div class="inputTitle">[Name]</div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="lastName"></input><sup>last</sup>
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="firstName"></input><sup>first</sup>
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="middleName"></input><sup>middle</sup>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>[SS#]</div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="socialFirst"></input>
    </div>
    -
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="socialMiddle"></input>
    </div>
    -
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="socialLast"></input>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

**In Google Chrome:**
[image: The form in browser]
can someone please explain why the elements top left corners don't start on the same y position since the height property increases towards the bottom of the page, not the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `vertical align` for `inline-block` elements is `baseline`. Change the the `vertical-align` to `top`.

```
form div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the default vertical alignment for inline elements is baseline, which is what you're seeing. Try changing it to top:

```
form > div { vertical-align:top}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using `vertical-align` you can use `flexbox`. By default, it will align the items for you, but you can use `align-items` to align them differently.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  form {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
form div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}
.inputContainer {
  display: inline-block;
}
.inputContainer input {
  display: block;
  width: 14em;
}
.inputTitle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <div class="inputTitle">[Name]</div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="lastName"></input><sup>last</sup>
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="firstName"></input><sup>first</sup>
    </div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="middleName"></input><sup>middle</sup>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>[SS#]</div>
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="socialFirst"></input>
    </div>
    -
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="socialMiddle"></input>
    </div>
    -
    <div class="inputContainer">
      <input type="text" name="socialLast"></input>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, this is useful information! I will explore the flexbox more, however, the explanation for why this was happeneing is what I was really looking to understand.